# Replicate photoshop focus stacking in python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, photoshop

Hi I am trying to focus stack a certain set of images. I have used photoshop to focus stack them but I am wondering is there a way to replicate how we focus stack the images in python using the same method in photoshop. My understanding of photoshop method is that it creates a mask of the original images and considers the focused areas in each image to create the final image. 
I have used this as a reference article: https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/ImageAlignment/image_alignment.py
https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/ImageAlignment-FeatureBased/align.py

What I have tried till now is find the homographies for two images and using ORB to find the key points and descriptors for image alignment. Based on these I am wraping the images to produce the final sharp image

```
 for i in range(0,len(matches)):
        image_1_points[i] = image_1_kp[matches[i].queryIdx].pt
        image_2_points[i] = image_2_kp[matches[i].trainIdx].pt


    homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(image_1_points, image_2_points, cv2.RANSAC, ransacReprojThreshold=2.0)

print( "Detecting features of base image")
    outimages.append(images[0])
    image1gray = cv2.cvtColor(images[0],cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image_1_kp, image_1_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(image1gray, None)

    for i in range(1,len(images)):
        print ("Aligning image {}".format(i))
        image_i_kp, image_i_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(images[i], None)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
            # This returns the top two matches for each feature point (list of list)
            pairMatches = bf.knnMatch(image_i_desc,image_1_desc, k=2)
            rawMatches = []
            for m,n in pairMatches:
                if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
                    rawMatches.append(m)

        sortMatches = sorted(rawMatches, key=lambda x: x.distance)
        matches = sortMatches[0:128]



        hom = findHomography(image_i_kp, image_1_kp, matches)
        newimage = cv2.warpPerspective(images[i], hom, (images[i].shape[1], images[i].shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

        outimages.append(newimage)
```

Comment: See http://enblend.sourceforge.net/enfuse.doc/enfuse_4.2.xhtml/enfuse.html#sec%3Afocus-stacks--depth-of-field-increase

Comment: @fmw42 correct me if I am wrong but I couldn't make out if the article you mentioned here uses python?

Comment: I do not know one way or the other. I just found that when searching about focus stacks. Thought it was interesting and to bring it to your attention.

Comment: @fmw42 well thanks for that. I'll have a look at it and maybe find something useful.